# github pages build and deployment failure

Tags: github, github-pages

I've followed [this](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/importing-your-projects-to-github/importing-source-code-to-github/adding-locally-hosted-code-to-github) and everything is set up. In Setting Pages Build and Deploy Source I have it set to Deploy from a branch and the branch is main. Code has all my files as uploaded from my local repo. I have a custom domain, it's entered (codeismathiscode.org) and it seems to be in permanent DNS Check in Progress, although Enforce HTTPS is checked. But Actions reports failures with pages build and deployment. My borgauf.github.io works, but my codeismathiscode.org, which should deploy from github repo omnimath gives a github 404. What's going wrong. This used to work.

Comment: Found these two: https://github.com/borgauf/codeismathiscode, https://github.com/borgauf/borgauf.github.io and both are empty, can you share the repo your files are uploaded onto?

Comment: Sorry, I'm trying to Pages-publish the omnimath repo with the domain name codeismathiscode.org. Got rid of the repo codeismathiscode...

Comment: are you using the "CNAME" method? like you need a way to tell github-pages that when someone goes to your domain, github pages should serve that content... not only that but you'll need to configure your DNS on your Admin Panel of your DNS provider too so that your DNS provider knows which server this DNS points to.

Comment: I created a new repo on github and moved everything over. It works now for borgauf.github.io/codeismathiscode Not going to try to fix the omnimath repo. Thanks for your input.